# Change the name of the deepest directory in a File object

Tags: java

I have File object in Java which is a directory path:

```
C:\foo\foo\bar
```

...and I would like to change this to:

```
C:\foo\foo\newname
```

I'm don't mean renaming the actual directory, but, simply modifying the path in the File object. Could someone show me how I can do this? Do I have to use string functions for this or is there some inbuilt Java function that I can use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct one File from another and get the parent directory of a file, combining these:

```
File orig = new File("C:\\foo\\foo\\bar");
File other = new File(orig.getParentFile(), "newname");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such method in java that changes path for the File object, however you can get the file path with getPath() or getAbsolutePath(). I think creating a new file at that path would do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only create a new `File` object with the new path:

```
File f2 = new File("C:\\foo\\foo\\newname")
```

Does it make any side effect on your code?

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
import java.io.File;
public class MainClass {
  public static void main(String[] a) {
    File file = new File("c:\\foo\\foo\\bar");
    file.renameTo(new File("c:\\foo\\foo\\newname"));
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: He doesn't want the actual name of the file to change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string-representation of the File object and search for the last / with indexOf(), then you change the value after it and create a new File object.

Comment: Use File.separatorChar not / though.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to something like this.

```
String sourcePath = "C:\\foo\\foo\\bar";
String newName = "newname";
File source = new File(sourcePath);
File dest = new File(source.getParent() + File.separator + newName);
source.renameTo(dest);
```